# How to pass a DBus variant to Qt's QDBusInterface::call

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qdbus, connman

I am trying to send the following message to [Connman](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/connman/connman.8.en.html) over Qt 5.12's DBus API:

```sh
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=net.connman / net.connman.Manager.SetProperty string:"OfflineMode" variant:boolean:true
```

As seen, the `SetProperty` method takes a dbus string and a dbus variant.

If I look at the signature with `qdbus`, I get the following:

```sh
$ qdbus --system net.connman / | grep Manager.SetProperty
method void net.connman.Manager.SetProperty(QString name, QDBusVariant value)
```

So that's what I do...

```cpp
iface.call("SetProperty", "OfflineMode", QDBusVariant(!m_flightModeOn));
```

However, I get the following compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QDBusInterface::call(const char [12], const char [12], QDBusVariant)’
         QDBusReply<QVariantMap> reply = iface.call("SetProperty", "OfflineMode", QDBusVariant(true));
```

Here is the complete function:

```cpp
void enableFlightMode()
{
    QDBusInterface iface("net.connman", "/", "net.connman.Manager", QDBusConnection::systemBus());
    if (iface.isValid()) {
        QDBusReply<QVariantMap> reply = iface.call("SetProperty", "OfflineMode", QDBusVariant(true));
    }

    qDebug() << qPrintable(QDBusConnection::systemBus().lastError().message());
}
```

I have tried passing both a `bool` and a `QVariant` to `::call`, but those result in DBus in a dbus error: `Method "SetProperty" with signature "sb" on interface "net.connman.Manager" doesn't exist`. This makes sense since the signature is a string and a variant.

I guess my question is, according to the [Qt DBus API type system docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.12/qdbustypesystem.html), QDBusVariant() is supposed to be analogous to the DBus "VARIANT", so I would expect to be able to pass it into this function. Is there another way I can pass a DBus variant through this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround using a different part of the API... Utilizing QDBusMessage, this can be done:

```cpp
    QDBusMessage message = QDBusMessage::createMethodCall("net.connman", "/", "net.connman.Manager", "SetProperty");
    QList<QVariant> arguments;
    arguments << "OfflineMode" << QVariant::fromValue(QDBusVariant(true));
    message.setArguments(arguments);
    QDBusConnection::systemBus().call(message);
    qDebug() << qPrintable(QDBusConnection::systemBus().lastError().message());
```

For anyone doing similar things with Connman, check out [cmst](https://github.com/andrew-bibb/cmst). It uses Qt to communicate with Connman over DBus.